# Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra

I got this error while executing `existsByEmail` method: `Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING`

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE user(id UUID, email varchar, first_name varchar, last_name varchar, PRIMARY KEY (id, email));
```

Tbe java spring code:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CassandraRepository<User, UUID> {
  boolean existsByEmail(String email);
}

@Table
@Data
public class User {

  @PrimaryKeyColumn(type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED, ordinal = 0)
  private UUID id;

  @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 1)
  private String email;

  @Column("first_name")
  private String firstName;

  @Column("last_name")
  private String lastName;
}
```

Please tell me why and solution for it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mar-Z makes a good suggestion about changing your data model.  How often will the user table be queried by `id`?  Is that something that you'll frequently have easy access to?  If not, re-keying the table like this will help:

```
CREATE TABLE user (
  id UUID, email varchar, first_name varchar, last_name varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY (email, id));
```

If you do have queries that require `id`, the best practice is to build a new query to support the new query.  You could completely duplicate the table if you don't mind keeping all of the data in-sync.  Or, you could just use it to reference the `id` for the `user` table, effectively making the table a "manual index" like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_by_email (
  id UUID, email varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY (email));
```

**Edit**

> How about if i want to search user by first name, last name, address?

First of all, there's a difference between "searching" and "querying."  With searching, you're providing very liberal keywords and expecting a large result set.  Querying is providing exact criteria and expecting a specific, usually small result set.

With that in mind, you'll want to make sure that your primary key definition matches your query criteria, in descending order of importance.  For this example, querying by first name wouldn't be terribly valuable, as common first names wouldn't lead to anything specific.  A table supporting a name query would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_by_name (
  id UUID, email varchar, first_name varchar, last_name varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY (last_name, first_name, id));
```

Basically, building a table for name queries would want to have `last_name` first, followed by `first_name` and `id` to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: How about if i want to search user by first name, last name, address?

Comment: mean that if I want to search/query by a field, I must create a copy of the table with this field is the first primary key? and how to make sure data are sync between tables?

Comment: @SoT You can keep them in sync using a CQL BATCH: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useBatchGoodExample.html

Answer (score 4):

You got this error because the underlying request does not use the partition key (id).

The email is, in your case a clustering column (as it is the default `PrimaryKeyColumn` when not explicitly provided)

With the bean you provided the only queries valid are

```
select * from user where id=?
select * from user where id=? AND email>?
select * from user where id=? AND email<?
select * from user where id=? AND email=?
```

**Why ?**

Data is partitioned based on the value of the partitioned key in order to access all data you want on a single node. You group together what you want to retrieve together. When you define a column as Partitioned column it becomes mandatory in all your queries.

With Apache Cassandra the data modeling strategy is to create your tables based on your queries. (If you need to access the same data with multiple requests to duplicate the data in multiple tables, it is the trade off for performance.

Answer (score 2):

> > why

Because email is the second (clustering) part of the primary key. Searching through it has a poor performance in Cassandra Store. Exactly what the warning is saying.

> > solution for it

If performance is not an issue in your application (like less then million of emails) then you can try allowing filtering.

Otherwise consider changing your model. I suggest to get rid of the id and use the email as the only primary (and partitioned) key.